# Как корректно вытащить значение параметра запроса?

Tags: rust, actix-web

Есть такой код запроса с фронтенда:

```
return axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8088/mike" , {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
  params: {
    foo: 'perfectGoods'
  }
})
.then(response => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

На бекенде прием данных происходит следующим образом:

```
use actix_cors::Cors;
use actix_web::{http, web, App, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Result};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MyObj {
    name: String,
}

async fn index(obj: web::Path<MyObj>) -> Result<HttpResponse> {
    Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().json(MyObj {
        name: obj.name.to_string(),
    }))
}


#[actix_rt::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {

    use actix_web::{App, HttpServer};

    HttpServer::new(|| App::new()
        .wrap(
            Cors::new() // <- Construct CORS middleware builder
              .allowed_origin("http://localhost:3000")
              .allowed_methods(vec!["GET", "POST"])
              .allowed_headers(vec![http::header::AUTHORIZATION, http::header::ACCEPT])
              .allowed_header(http::header::CONTENT_TYPE)
              .max_age(3600)
              .finish())
        .service(
            web::resource("")
              .route(web::get().to(index))
              .route(web::head().to(|| HttpResponse::MethodNotAllowed())
        ))
        .route(r"{name}", web::get().to(index)))
        .bind("127.0.0.1:8088")?
        .run()
        .await
}
```

Вопрос:
Каким образом, на бекенде, можно вытащить передаваемое с фронтенда значение `foo: 'perfectGoods'`?

Пытался пробовать разные примеры с данного мануала:
https://actix.rs/docs/extractors/

Но необходимой задачи выполнить с помощью него не удалось.
(Некоторые примеры выдают ошибку в компиляторе - некоторые мне не до конца ясно по какому принципу функционируют.)
Хотелось бы увидеть самый примитивный вариант получения данного значения, для начала..

Comment: https://docs.rs/actix-web/3.1.0/actix_web/web/struct.Query.html

Comment: https://actix.rs/docs/extractors/#query пример сразу над оглавлением - извлечение значений из запроса